# Rails -- line breaks appearing between form fields with errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble trying to get rid of the extra line breaks Rails seems to insert between fields with errors.

I created a new rails app, created a scaffolding called "users" with a name and an age, and then said `validates :name, :presence => true` and `validates :age, :presence => true`.  Then I booted up the `users/new` page and just clicked "submit" without entering anything in the fields to generate the error page.  What happened was that between the "name" label and the field for entering the name, an extra line break was inserted.  Same with the "age" label and its field.  How do I stop this extra line break from happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ach, just got bitten by this one too.

When you have form fields with errors rails changes the output of form helper methods like #label and #text_field.

The result is your nice little "label" and "input" tags are still being emitted - just "stealth" wrapped with a surrounding div.  For example:

```
f.label :name
```

goes from:

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
```

to:

```
<div class="field_with_errors"><label for="name">Name</label></div>
```

The default behavior of a div is "block" - which is causing your line breaks.

You can fix this by changing the css.  As an example:

```
div.field_with_errors {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: thank you, that worked :) good call -- i noticed the stealth wrapping with that div but I didn't think to change the behavior of a div to that of a span... well done sir

Answer (score 0):

```
.field_with_errors:nth-child(odd) {
  padding: 2px;
  display: table;
}
.field_with_errors:nth-child(even) {
 padding: 2px;
 display: inline;
}
```

That's what I ended up changing mine to, since the extra line breaks were sort of nice on the labels but I didn't want the line breaks on the actual form fields.